# Function misinterpreted as property in Angular2?

Tags: angular

Starting to experiment with Angular2. The error is in this block, on the call to `this.auth.isLoggedIn()`. I get a `Property 'isLoggedIn' does not exist on type 'AuthService'.` error. Why is the function call being interpreted as a property access?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate() {
    if(!this.auth.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.router.navigate[''];
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the service being injected:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private loggedIn:boolean = false;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.loggedIn = !!localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
  }

  login(email:string, password:string):void {
    localStorage.setItem('auth_token', 'x');
    this.loggedIn = true;
  }

  logout():void {
    localStorage.removeItem('auth_token');
    this.loggedIn = false;
  }

  isLoggedin():boolean {
    return this.loggedIn;
  }
}
```

Comment: isLoggedin()  (the method name) <> isLoggedIn().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change your service's method signature from `isLoggedin() : boolean`  to `isLoggedIn() : boolean`.

Comment: Crap. I am embarrassed to see that. :)

Comment: No prob, I embarrass myself religiously.